How to share my entire screen during a Zoom video call on my Macbook Pro with someone else?
I have Zoom calls with students and an administrator would like to see my entire screen while I am giving a lecture to give me pointers. What are some feasible ways to do this? I have a few ideas:

Use Teamviewer to share my entire screen while using Zoom, but I am concerned this might introduce issues as two video call softwares are being used.
Use an HDMI to USB-C capture card to grab the HDMI output of my Macbook with the Zoom call and send it to a second Macbook, which I then share with the admin using Teamviewer.

I am wondering on the feasibility of the above and if there are any better ideas for this. Thanks very much.

Why not just add the administrator to the Zoom call directly? Also, combining Teamviewer and Zoom is something you can easily test yourself.

This is what we do at our school - invite the Admin. There is no reason to hide the Admin’s  presence, and  most likely doing so would violate transparency regulations and have legal repercussions.
